# React native google sign in failed . Error code 10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-api

I am trying to add google sign in in react native application. I followed all the steps in the [official doccument](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin).
Everything working fine but after signing in it through error saying

> WRONG SIGNIN {"name":"GoogleSignInError","code":10}

My sign in page is like this.

```
import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';

  componentDidMount(){
        GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true }).then(() => {
            // play services are available. can now configure library
        }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
        });

        GoogleSignin.configure({
         scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],//Even if i remove this the thing is same
            webClientId: "********-**********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        }).then(() => {

        });
    }

  googleSignIn=()=>{
        GoogleSignin.signIn()
            .then((user) => {
                console.log(user);           
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('WRONG SIGNIN error', err);
            })
            .done();
    };


//Google button
 <Button onPress={()=>this.googleSignIn()}>
  <Icon style={styles.googleIcon} name="google-plus" type="FontAwesome"/>
 </Button>
```

My google developer console setup is like this
[image]

I tried to check the issue on the github issu tracer and tried their solution but no luck. 
Can anyone please tell me where i am doing wrong? As you can see i am using example code of [react native google signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin)

Comment: Have you added correct SHA1 key? If you working on signed apk thn you should have created SHA1 key using your keystore file.

Comment: yes i have creared sha1 key and added

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/562f5719289362a589ff8366e0b4bcd91b64a644/android-guide.md#e-getting-developer_error-error-message-on-android-when-trying-to-login) , It might help you.

Comment: Yes i followed that document to set up the project

Comment: @user7747472 Are you able to solve this issue. i have a same problem today.

Comment: @SagarChavada, Hi sagar yes i was able to solve the issue , for me it was issue with the client id. and make sure u have firebase setup too. 
You may check this link https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/120

Answer (score 1):

You Should go to the Google Play Console and open Your App then click on app integrity which come under Setup.[image] then click on App signing and copy SHA-1 fingerprint.
Now got to firebase open your app project setting [image] now click on add fingerprint now pest that SHA-1 key and save.
Now your google sing in will work.